# Stuck with Angularjs

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, angularjs

Hello i'm new to angularjs and i'm creating an Angularjs application with visualstudio 2012 mvc4 and i need some help with a request.

this is my get method

```
    // GET: /getCard/
    Logic l = new Logic();
    public List<Cards> Index()
    {
        var cards = ml.getSortedDeck(); 
        return cards;
    }
```

here is my js code

```
  MemoryApp.factory('Cards', function($resource){
    return $resource('/getCard/', { method: 'GET', isArray: true });
 });


 var ColourCtrl = function ($scope, Cards, $routeParams, $resource) {
$scope.cards = [];

$scope.setcards = function () {
    Cards.query(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        $scope.cards = $scope.cards.concat(data);
    });
}

$scope.setcards();
```

}

when i stepped through my backend code it worked fine, i got 16 hits back in the "cards" list which is the right amount. Though when i check my console.log on the website i have an array with 59 items that are unuseable to me.

When i check the response section in under the network tab i get this message
"System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Memory.Models.Cards]" and that seems right to me.

best regards /M

Comment: jumpingcode that didnt change anything, i still got the same result as before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return JSON.

```
public JsonResult Index()
{
    var cards = ml.getSortedDeck(); 
    return Json(cards, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```